# gprof Not Showing Call Information

Tags: fortran, profiling, gprof

I successfully compile and run my Fortran code with the -pg flag using the gfortran compiler. gprof produces a gmon.out file. When I run gprof on the file and take a look at the resultant *.txt file, I see:

```
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name
21.53     24.46    24.46                             fcn_x
12.45     38.60    14.14                             fcn_y
11.36     51.50    12.90                             fcn_z

. . .
```

etc. for about 180 functions.

There is zero call information in the call columns, and there's no call graph. At least one of these functions is definitely called. Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be helpful to show exactly how you are compiling the program. But at a guess does including -g help?

Comment: Functions called through function pointers don't generate that information.  Also, dynamic libraries may pose difficulties.

Comment: @IanBush: Tried including -g, but to no avail. 
Tim, unfortunately, my case is neither of those. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb mistake - left out "-pg" in the compilation statement. Only linked.